# How to print the current register values from kernel code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to print the current register values at multiple points, from my kernel module.
This is the code I am using:

```
struct pt_regs *regs = task_pt_regs(current);
show_regs(regs);
```

This works, but looks like the context is not correct.
For e.g, epc always show below value, though I have this code at multiple places in my file.

```
kernel: epc   : ffffffff8023a510 kernel_thread_helper+0x0/0x18
```

i.e function name is always "kernel_thread_helper".

In case of kernel panic, I get the epc value pointing to my function name + offset, e.g:

```
kernel: epc   : ffffffffc0087ef0 my_function+0x58/0xa0 [myModule]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note:
I was not able to directly use the actual definition of show_regs, since it is not exported in the kernel code (so I will get a 'undefined symbol' error).
As a workaround, I copied the function dentition of show_regs, as it is, to my module.  Hopefully, this should not cause any issue.

Comment: If you wish to access unexported symbol, I suggest to refer this blog last section. http://onebitbug.me/2011/03/04/introducing-linux-kernel-symbols/

Comment: And also mention exact arch. It will helpful to analyze.

Comment: `current` is a macro for the current task.  You are in the kernel, not the kernel task, so the registers won't change.  It is much easier just to use `printk("%s:%d\n", __function__, __line__);`.  Why would you want to print a `PC`.  The call site of `show_regs()` is known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it, below code works! :)

```
struct pt_regs regs;
prepare_frametrace(&regs);
show_regs(&regs);
```

Comment: `prepare_frametrace` is an architecture-specific function that is only declared in [arch/mips/include/*](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.197/A/ident/prepare_frametrace), if I am wrong, please point me out.